# Как разобраться с % по отношению к числу, и написать условие

Tags: visual-c++, objective-c, c

Помогите мне разобраться.
Задача такая. Есть предел чисел от 1 до 1000. Есть загаданное число рендомом, например 840, и есть число которое я ввёл, например: сначало 650 потом 920.

Так вот, как определить % по отношению к числу которое было загаданное?

Чтоб было более понятно, у меня есть список картинок которую нужно выводить если приблизился к числу на

```
от50%до75%=1.png, 
от75%до90%=2.png,
от90%до97%=3.png,
от97%до99%=4.png.
```

(я думаю сделать это методом case of)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var промежуточное = (загаданное число) / (введенное число);
if (промежуточное > 1) {
    промежуточное = 1/промежуточное;
}
процент_попадания = промежуточное * 100;
```

Comment: Именно то что надо))) класс))) спасибо !!!

Answer (score 0):

650/1000 это процент от

920/1000 это процент до

840/1000 это процент загаданный

значение процента от 0 до 1

получаем
от: 0,65 (т.е. 65 процентов)
до: 0,92 (т.е. 92 процента)
загаданное число: 0,84 (т.е. 84 процента)

тупой ифчик:

```
if(0.50>загаданное чилос && загаданное число <0.75) 1.png
if(0.75>загаданное чилос && загаданное число <0.90) 2.png
if(0.90>загаданное чилос && загаданное число <0.97) 3.png
if(0.97>загаданное чилос && загаданное число <0.99) 4.png
```

Comment: почему 650/1000, а не 650/840 ? мне же нужно решить чем ближе у загаданному я подобрался, а загаданное у нас 840. 650-вводимое . 
if(0.50> i && i <0.75) 1.png так получаеться если i=0.65 ?

Comment: sry видимо не так понял вопрос.